# nginx rewrite odoo 8

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, odoo-8

I am having a few issues trying to rewrite some URLs in nginx.

I have a basic website made using Odoo's CMS. My goal is to make the URLs "pretty"

eg. example.com/services would be what the customer types in and sees in the URL bar but it loads example.com/pages/website.services

The rewrites I have are

```
location /services {
    rewrite / /page/website.services last;
}

location /news {
    rewrite / /blog last;
}

location /contact-us {
    rewrite / /page/website.contactus last;
}
```

/contact-us and /news work as intended but /services is still showing example.com/page/services in the URL bar instead of example.com/services

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I managed to solve my problem.

my rewrites that work are:

```
location /services {
    rewrite / /page/services last;
}

location /news {
    rewrite / /blog last;
}

location /contact-us {
    rewrite / /page/contactus last;
}
```

I'm not entirely sure why but I think it may have something to do with Odoo doing its own redirects which is why I thought /page/website.services was an actual page.
It confused me somewhat because the /page/website.contactus was working. It may have been because the contactus is created with a module and the services was just created as a page.

If anyone else has a better explanation feel free to post.